# Filter Doesn't display data using AngularJS -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, i am trying to apply a filter to some data i'm displaying. However, as soon as i include the filter in my code i can't even see the data that was previously being displayed like it should be. I've looked into filters for AngularJS and even creating my own. It seems pretty straight-forward and easy enough to implement but what kinds of problems occur with filters? I'm looking for constructive criticism for AngularJS and Javascript, NOT for my skills as a computer scientist. Any negative comments will be deleted and reputation for those people will be hurt!

```
<thead>
    <tr ng-if="vm.detail == false">
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="filter.DivisionName" class="input-sm form-control" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="filter.PoolName" class="input-sm form-control" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="filter.SubpoolName" class="input-sm form-control" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="filter.RenewalGroupName" class="input-sm form-control" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="filter.MchNumber" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="filter.ContractNumber" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="filter.PlanCode" /></th>
    </tr>


</thead>
<tbody >
<!--Data for Division, Pool, Subpool, and RenewalGroup Searches-->
 <tr ng-repeat="plan in vm.plans| filter:filter |limitTo:vm.pageSize "
     ng-if="vm.detail == false">

     <td>{{plan.ExperienceGroup.RenewalGroup.Subpool.Pool.Division.DivisionName}}</td>
     <td>{{plan.ExperienceGroup.RenewalGroup.Subpool.Pool.PoolName}}</td>
     <td>{{plan.ExperienceGroup.RenewalGroup.Subpool.SubpoolName}}</td>
     <td>{{plan.ExperienceGroup.RenewalGroup.RenewalGroupName}}</td>
     <td><a href="#/Mch/MCH/{{plan.MchNumber}}">{{plan.MchNumber}}</a></td>
     <td>{{plan.PlanDesign.ContractNumber}}</td>
     <td>{{plan.PlanDesign.PlanCode}}</td>
     <td>{{plan.Mcp}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: You should check that your filter function is defined in the correct scope (maybe you have nested controller?). Try logging your  filter `arguments` and return value just to make sure it is being called as you expect.

Comment: Great suggestion! It turns out to look just as it should: 

{"RenewalGroupName":"df","SubpoolName":"sdf","PoolName":"asdg","DivisionName":"awd","PlanCode":"sdf","ContractNumber":"sdf","MchNumber":"sdf"}
Division Pool Subpool RenewalGroup MCH Contract PlanCode

Comment: Make sure you are returning a boolean, that's the only other thing I can think off

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a boolean and it's values get changed as they should.